# Override vendor file issue in magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, static-content-deploy

I am trying to override the below class file in my custom module.

Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent.php

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent" 
   type="Vendor\Module\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent"/>    
   </config>
```

**Vendor\Module\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent.php**

```
 <?php

 namespace Vendor\Module\Deploy\Service;

 class DeployStaticContent extends \Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent
 {

  public function deploy(array $options)
  {
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('deployment start--');
    $version = !empty($options[Options::CONTENT_VERSION]) && is_string($options[Options::CONTENT_VERSION])
        ? $options[Options::CONTENT_VERSION]
        : (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp();
    $this->versionStorage->save($version);

    if ($this->isRefreshContentVersionOnly($options)) {
        $this->logger->warning("New content version: " . $version);
        return;
    }

    $queueOptions = [
        'logger' => $this->logger,
        'options' => $options,
        'maxProcesses' => $this->getProcessesAmount($options),
        'deployPackageService' => $this->objectManager->create(
            \Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage::class,
            [
                'logger' => $this->logger
            ]
        )
    ];

    if (isset($options[Options::MAX_EXECUTION_TIME])) {
        $queueOptions['maxExecTime'] = (int)$options[Options::MAX_EXECUTION_TIME];
    }

    $deployStrategy = $this->deployStrategyFactory->create(
        $options[Options::STRATEGY],
        ['queue' => $this->queueFactory->create($queueOptions)]
    );

    $packages = $deployStrategy->deploy($options);

    if ($options[Options::NO_JAVASCRIPT] !== true) {
        $deployRjsConfig = $this->objectManager->create(
            DeployRequireJsConfig::class,
            ['logger' => $this->logger]
        );
        $deployI18n      = $this->objectManager->create(
            DeployTranslationsDictionary::class,
            ['logger' => $this->logger]
        );
        foreach ($packages as $package) {
            if (!$package->isVirtual()) {
                $deployRjsConfig->deploy($package->getArea(), $package->getTheme(), $package->getLocale());
                $deployI18n->deploy($package->getArea(), $package->getTheme(), $package->getLocale());
            }
        }
    }

    if ($options[Options::NO_JAVASCRIPT] !== true && $options[Options::NO_JS_BUNDLE] !== true) {
        $deployBundle = $this->objectManager->create(
            Bundle::class,
            ['logger' => $this->logger]
        );
        foreach ($packages as $package) {
            if (!$package->isVirtual()) {
                $deployBundle->deploy($package->getArea(), $package->getTheme(), $package->getLocale());
            }
        }
    }

    if ($options[Options::NO_HTML_MINIFY] !== true) {
        $this->objectManager->get(MinifyTemplates::class)->minifyTemplates();
      }
    
  }
}
```

This seems not working, can anyone help me with this, I want to write custom code after the static content deploy activity.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following changes:

```
     <preference 
       for="Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent" 
       type="Vendor\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent"
     />
```

Module to be 'Deploy'.

Also replace you code from path

`Vendor\Module\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent.php`

to

`Vendor\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent.php`

Let me know if it helps.